# SSIS, how to use value from a config file?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I've created a Business Intelligence Project using MS Visual Studio 2008.
In the dtsx I've a simple Mail Task. How can I use MailTo variable from dtsConfig file ?

`<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Variables[User::MailTo].Properties[Value]" ValueType="String">
  <ConfiguredValue>hello@world.com</ConfiguredValue> 
  </Configuration>`

Now I'm using windows batch script to run this dtsx package.

```
dtexec /f "D:\MyPath\Sample.dtsx" /conf "D:\MyPath\Sample.dtsConfig"
```

When I execute after changing the config file variable `[User::MailTo]`, then its not woking.
It's sending the mail to the previous mail id.

How can I use the variable `[User::MailTo]` from dtsConfig file at runtime ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The Variable exists in SSIS at the root/package level. Variables can exist in other scopes so it is important to identify where one exists.

The Configuration file you are using assigns at run-time a value of "hello@world.com" to @[User::MailTo]

If you had raised an event, you could see the value of MailTo changes from the design time value TempExpt@other.net to the value from the configuration file. The trick now is to have the Mail Task use a variable instead of a hard coded value.

This is accomplished through Expressions. Every object in SSIS exposes an Expressions collection. You may have a seeming simple package but it could be wired from here to infinity with Expressions linked to other Expressions. I often mention that the difference between professionals and the duffers is the judicious use of Expressions, Configurations and Logging.

Double click the Send Mail Task and there should be an Expressions tab. In there, in the first grid, click the drop down until you find the To field. In the next column, use your Variable `@[User::MailTo]`

While you can use an editor to construct complex Expressions on a object, I *strongly* advise against this. Create a Variable, use the wicked complex expression logic there and in your object, simply reference the Variable. The reason for this is support and maintenance. You cannot inspect an object to see what the expressions are. If they are bad, your package blows up and you have no recourse for troubleshooting. If it's just an expression, you can set a breakpoint on them and then inspect you Variable looking for what is amiss.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. yes i've used expression in MailTask. Variable exists at package level. but it's not working. should i change the variable to task level ?

Comment: Nope, leave it at the package level. Define "it's not working"